# Recaptcha on WordPress does not work

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

Recaptcha plugin installed on WordPress website does not work. Every time I try to log in, it displays an error: *You have entered an incorrect reCAPTCHA value.*
We already tried to reinstall it. The error is the same.

Comment: Can you share the link of the site? How did you set it up? It's very hard to help you just from an error message.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Please take a look at it here: https://inevitablebliss.com/wp-login.php?action=register